# Loading mixed inscure display content crossdomain.xml

Tags: xml, flash, flash-builder4.5

Hey guys some background, I've never worked with flash (mainly RoR/JS), so I'm not even sure how to tackle this issue.  Switching our app to https, our only flash app hangs and doesn't work. The warnings in the console seems to be the issue.

Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml"

Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "http://fpdownload.adobe.com/crossdomain.xml"

I've been digging around and saw this,

[displayed insecure content from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/crossdomain.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319856/displayed-insecure-content-from-http-fpdownload-adobe-com-crossdomain-xml)

But it seems to me like there should be an easier way maybe pointing to:

Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "**https**://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml"

Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "**https**://fpdownload.adobe.com/crossdomain.xml"

Is there a way I can set it like this, in maybe FlashBuilder (I just installed this).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?