# How to load adobe plugins from https?

Tags: apache-flex, https, adobe, flash

I have my website hosted on HTTPS and I have developed a webplayer using FlashBuilder. But when I access webplayer from my website, its showing this warning.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/myvideo' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure plugin data 'http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

The page at 'https://www.example.com/myvideo' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure plugin data 'http://fpdownload.adobe.com/crossdomain.xml'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Because of this warning my HTTPS status not showing in secured green color.[Attachment]

[image]
Where I can change these settings in my flashbuilder? How to change this HTTP request to HTTPS?

Comment: This might answer your question ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319856/displayed-insecure-content-from-http-fpdownload-adobe-com-crossdomain-xml